# Unity stopping part of a raycast

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a gameobject (a bomb) which detects other gameobjects around the bomb and if they are within the radius and are a rigidbody, the gameobjects would propel away from the bomb.

I also want to make it so that if a gameobject is shielded by a gameobject that is immune to the explosion, both gameobjects wouldn't be propelled away even if they are inside the radius of the bomb.

I'm having trouble stopping the force added to gameobjects within the radius of the bomb that are shielded, but also adding force to objects within the radius without another gameobject shielding it. Sorry if it doesn't really make sense.

Here is the code I'm using to propel gameobjects away from the bomb:

```
Collider[] colliders = Physics.OverlapSphere(transform.position, radius);

foreach (Collider hit in colliders)
{
  Rigidbody hitRigidbody = hit.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
  
  if (hitRigidbody)
  {
    Vector3 direction = hitRigidbody.transform.position - transform.position;
    hitRigidbody.AddForce(direction.normalized * power, ForceMode.Impulse);
  }
}
```

I tried detecting if the gameobjects in the radius were of a certain layer. If so, it would skip past the code that propels gameobjects from the bomb. However, it wasn't what I wanted because for example, if there were four gameobjects inside the radius of the bomb, and only one gameobject was being shielded, the code I wrote would completely stop the code so none of the gameobjects would be propelled.

I was wondering if there was a way to stop part of the raycast if it hit a gameobject with a specific layer and what would be the best way to approach this.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'shielded'?

Comment: So. If its got something in the way you would need to do a raycast to determine if its blocked or not. Your code has nothing to cover the "shielded" aspect

Comment: @shingo If a game object that is immune to the explosion is in front of another game object that isn't

Comment: @BugFinder I'm seeking help to find a good way to approach this problem. Sorry for not specifying it.

Comment: You probably need a raycast from the hit object back to the bomb to check if something between them

Answer (score 0):

Once you get the list of colliders that are within your "blast radius" by using OverlapSphere, you will need to filter them to determine which ones are affected by the blast and which ones ignore it.  You mentioned checking against the layer and this is a good way to go.

The step you are missing is to then iterate over each of those affected colliders and do a raycast to it to see if something is in the way.  How you want your objects to respond will determine what kind of raycast you want to do.

If a "blastable" object is in front of another "blastable" object, should the first shield the second?  If so, you can just do a normal Raycast and if you hit anything before hitting your collider-in-question, it is shielded.

However, if only certain objects can be a shield, I recommend using `RaycastAll` ([link](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.RaycastAll.html)).  This will return an array of hits and you will have to iterate through the list to see if any "shield" objects stand between your collider and your blast origin.

```
Collider[] colliders = Physics.OverlapSphere(transform.position, radius);

foreach (Collider hit in colliders)
{
  Rigidbody hitRigidbody = hit.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
  
  if (hitRigidbody)
  {
    //TODO!! check the hit transform to see what layer it is on.
    //  you don't need to process non-blastable objects
    if (hit.transform.layer != BlastableLayer) continue;

    Vector3 direction = hitRigidbody.transform.position - transform.position;

    //TODO!! if anything can be a shield, just do a simple raycast.
    //You could also do a SphereCast if you want your blast evaluation to have "size"
    
    RaycastHit blockerhit;
    bool isblocked = Physics.Raycast(transform.position, direction.normalized, out blockerhit, direction.magnitude);
    if (isblocked && blockerhit != null)
    {
         //Check if something other than the collider-in-question is intersected
         if (blockerhit.collider.gameObject!= hit.gameObject)
         {
           //TODO!! Do you need to do a layer check? If "anything" can be a shield
           //  you probably just want to bail
           continue;
         }
    }
    
    //TODO!! Otherwise, if only certain things can be "shields"
    RaycastHit[] possibles;
    possibles= Physics.RaycastAll(transform.position, direction.normalized, direction.magnitude);
    foreach(RaycastHit ps in possibles)
    {
         //TODO!! if the ps object is of the correct "shield" layer and is at a 
         //  closer distance to transform.position than the collider does, it
         // is blocking.  If blocking, just use 'continue' to bail.
    }
    
    hitRigidbody.AddForce(direction.normalized * power, ForceMode.Impulse);
  }
}
```

Note that just as there is SphereCast, there is also SphereCastAll that works in the exact same manner.

Also, on a more functional note, your blast "power" should probably fall of as a function of distance squared.  So an object near the edge of radius would receive a much less powerful blast than an object right near the center.